# java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: servlets

i have written the code of jsp,servlet for uploading the Doc file in database.

here is my code,but i am getting the error like this==java.io.FileNotFoundException: insert into resume(resume) values(?) (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) .please help me how to remove this error???

```
           try
    {   

    Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://W2K8SERVER:1433/career","sa","Alpha#123" );

        pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from data1 where email=? and password=?");   


        pst = con.prepareStatement
        ("insert into resume(resume) "+ "values(?)");

        File re = new File("" + pst);
        fis = new FileInputStream(re);
        pst.setBinaryStream(3, (InputStream)fis, (int)(re.length()));
        pst.setString (1,upload);


        //rs = pst.executeQuery();


        while (rs.next())
            cnt ++;

        int s = pst.executeUpdate();
        if(s>0) {
          System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
         }
        else {
        System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload image.");
          }
                    rs.close();
        pst.close();   
        con.close();
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Servlet for sending the text or document file to the SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336295/servlet-for-sending-the-text-or-document-file-to-the-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

It is because `insert into resume(resume) values(?)` is probably not the name of a file on your disk.

```
  pst = con.prepareStatement ("insert into resume(resume) "+ "values(?)");
  File re = new File("" + pst);
```

You are creating a `File` from `""+ pst`, which is the result of `toString()` being called on a `PreparedStatement`. Did you put in the `""` to get rid of the informative compilation error?

You probably have the real filename in some other variable.

```
 File re = new File(theRealFileNameVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File re = new File("" + pst);
```

please make sure the "pst" value is a valid file path, apparently the value "**insert into resume(resume) values(?)**" is not a valid file path

Answer (score 0):

The java.io.File class has four (4) constructors

```
File(File parent, String child)
File(String pathname)
File(String parent, String child)
File(URI uri)
```

In your case you are trying to pass to the constructor an object or type `java.sql.PreparedStatement` that you trying to cast into a String. I don't see how (even if you arrived to convert pst into a string) pst will reference a path to a file. Please go back and read a little bit about java.io.

.